# Type PaymentPubKeyHash not found

Tags: types

I have the following datum type

```
data ProjectSubmitDatum = ProjectSubmitDatum
  { vProjectOwner :: PaymentPubKeyHash,
    vProjectRegistrationFee :: Integer,
    vProjectCategory :: BuiltinByteString,
    vFundPayIdentifier :: PaymentPubKeyHash
  }
  deriving (Show)
```

I also have the module imported like this

```
import Ledger.Address
```

The following error pops up when i run cabal repl

```
src/QuadraticVFSC.hs:45:19: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘PaymentPubKeyHash’
   |
45 |   { vFundOwner :: PaymentPubKeyHash,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import either the whole module like this:

```
import Ledger
```

or the specific type like this:

```
import Ledger (PaymentPubKeyHash)
```

Comment: Still not working when i import the whole module. When i was importing specific type it said it does not export PaymentPubKeyHash.

Comment: Also check you have the right git commits (precisely the commit of `plutus-apps` as found in the `cabal.project`). `PaymentPub...` is relatively new. It used to just be `Pub...`

Comment: If it can’t be found, you most probably have an older version of plutus-apps. You can change the tags in the file cabal.project.

Answer (score 2):

You neeed to import PaymentPubKeyHash it like the following:

`import Ledger.Address qualified as Address                      (Address, PaymentPubKeyHash(..))`

This works for me and you can checkout my working code on testnet here:

https://github.com/lley154/cardano-lottery/blob/main/src/OnChain.hs

Cheers,

Lawrence